# Error: Inlining of fonts failed. Connection TImedOut after upgrading Angular 11 to 12

Tags: angular, angular12, angular-upgrade

I have upgraded my project from Angular 11 to 12. Below is the version I am using. But while compiling, it fails.

> Error: Inlining of fonts failed. An error has occurred while retrieving https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons over the internet.
> connect ETIMEDOUT 142.250.185.74:443

I have set Http proxy in .npmrc file.

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.18
Node: 12.14.1
Package Manager: npm 6.13.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 12.2.17
animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
router


Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.18
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.18
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.18
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    12.2.18
@angular/flex-layout            11.0.0-beta.33
@angular/forms                  11.2.14
@angular/material               12.2.13
@schematics/angular             12.2.18
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.3.5
```

I have tried setting proxy in .npmrc and it is not working